# Efficient tidyverse way of finding value at given date in data set with historic changes

Tags: r, tidyverse, lubridate

Given a tibble of historic changes I want to efficiently create a tibble with what value each id had at a given date.

**Example**

```
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)

df <- tribble(
  ~id, ~value, ~date_created,
  1, "a", as_date("2020-01-01"),
  1, "b", as_date("2020-01-06"),
  1, "c", as_date("2020-02-01"),
  2, "Y", as_date("2020-01-01"),
  2, "Z", as_date("2020-01-02")
)

# function should output a tibble with one row per id with the value it had at that date
get_value_at_date <- function(df, date){}
```

`get_value_at_date(df, as_date("2019-01-01"))` should have output `tribble(~id,~value,1,NA,2,NA)`

`get_value_at_date(df, as_date("2020-01-06"))` should have output `tribble(~id,~value,1,"b",2,"Z")`

`get_value_at_date(df, as_date("2020-03-01"))` should have output `tribble(~id,~value,1,"c",2,"Z")`

**Example Solution Function**

```
get_value_at_date <- function(df, date){

 # find the last change before the date
 value_at_date_df <- df %>% 
   arrange(id, date_created) %>% 
   group_by(id) %>% 
   filter(date_created <= date) %>% 
   slice_tail(n = 1) %>%
   select(id,value)
 
 # value could be of many class types, and need a unique NA for each
 value_class <- class(df %>% select(value) %>% pull())
 # we're assuming as.CLASS(NA) works for all CLASS inputs
 bespoke_na <- eval(parse(text=paste0("as.",value_class,"(NA)")))
 
 # find any that have been removed so should be blank
 missed_ids <- df %>% 
   anti_join(value_at_date_df, by = "id") %>%
   pull(id) %>% 
   unique() 
 # make it a df
 missed_ids_df <- tibble(
   id = missed_ids,
   value = bespoke_na
 )
 
 # attach the 2 dfs
 out_df <- bind_rows(value_at_date_df,missed_ids_df) %>% 
   arrange(id) %>%
   ungroup()
 
 return(out_df)
}
```

I have the following two issues with my solution:

1. it seems fairly slow, especially when scaled up to the actual data (of the order of thousands of rows).
2. the use of `eval` to guess the class of NA does not feel like good practice. The reason for this is the function's input tibble could have the value column as any class. I do not know if for every class *--class--* the function as.*--class--* exists.

Comment: All the `value` columns return `NA` when running your function. Eg - `get_value_at_date(df, as_date("2019-01-06"))`

Comment: Sorry @RonakShah that was a typo in the example outputs - fixed now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.preserve` argument to `filter` removes the need to handle removed groups.

`last` uses `dplyr:::default_missing` for sensible missing values, but that can be overriden if needed.

```
get_value_at_date_2 <- function(df, date){
  df %>% 
    group_by(id) %>% 
    dplyr::filter(date_created <= date, .preserve = TRUE) %>% 
    summarize(value = dplyr::last(value, order_by = date_created))
}

get_value_at_date_2(df, as_date("2019-01-01")) 
#> `summarise()` ungrouping output (override with `.groups` argument)
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>      id value
#>   <dbl> <chr>
#> 1     1 <NA> 
#> 2     2 <NA>
    
get_value_at_date_2(df, as_date("2020-01-06"))
#> `summarise()` ungrouping output (override with `.groups` argument)
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>      id value
#>   <dbl> <chr>
#> 1     1 b    
#> 2     2 Z

get_value_at_date_2(df, as_date("2020-03-01")) 
#> `summarise()` ungrouping output (override with `.groups` argument)
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>      id value
#>   <dbl> <chr>
#> 1     1 c    
#> 2     2 Z
```

(Benchmarking is left out, as it is better conducted at mid to actual scale on real data, and would probably be meaningless on example data above. If performance remains an issue, consider the `data.table` package, that can mix with the `tidyverse`).

---

I ended up running a benchmark, and the performance is not really better

```
create_df <- function(n, rows_to_groups_ratio, seed = 123) {
  set.seed(seed)
  tibble(
    id = sample(sample(n %/% rows_to_groups_ratio, 1), n, replace = TRUE),
    value = sample(c(letters, LETTERS), n, replace = TRUE),
    date_declared = sample(seq(as.Date("2019-01-01"), as.Date("2020-07-01"), "day"), 
                           n, replace = TRUE)
  )
}

mybench <- bench::press(
  n = c(1e3, 10e3, 100e3, 1e6),
  rows_to_groups_ratio = c(3, 5, 10, 50, 100),
  {
    df <- create_df(n, rows_to_groups_ratio)
    date <- as.Date("2020-01-01")
    bench::mark(
      get_value_at_date(df, date),
      get_value_at_date_2(df, date) 
    )
  }
)

autoplot(mybench)
```

[image]